# Does Ubuntu support the Venix 80286 file-system?

Tags: filesystem

I need to know, if Ubuntu supports the venix 80286 file-system.
the HDD is fine, but I need to read, the file-system, and to copy some files of it!

i couldn't find anything useful on Google, and Askubuntu.

**Question**:*Does Ubuntu support the venix 80286 file-system?*

Comment: System V. Nostalgic <3. Damn @alci I should learn not to comment and just make an answer. I had almost the same text ready to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no access to a Venix file system, but it seems that Venix fielsystem is also known as System V filesystem.

Loading the module for sysv works on Ubuntu:

```
sudo modprobe sysv
```

So it seems the fielsystem is supported.

You should issue the following command and get the filesystem mounted;

```
mount -t sysv /dev/sdX /media/mountpoint
```

Then browes it in /media/mountpoint...

I cannot test, but it should work.

Comment: Documentation on SysV kernel module [is here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/sysv-fs.txt;h=253b50d1328ed8d62e873f9e6ca750972bc603ce;hb=HEAD)! *"It implements all of Xenix FS, SystemV/386 FS, Coherent FS."*

Comment: @alci, If i would typ this in a different distribution then Ubuntu, like parted magic, should it work. Don't have a Ubuntu machine/USB/CD/DVD, at hand right now! :(

Comment: Well, it really depends on the kernel that is submitted with your distro. Does it have the sysv module cimpiled in, or available as a module, or not at all. If 1 or 2, it should work. If 3, you would have to recompile, or rather find another distro.